# Searching in Eclipse e4xmi editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

Is there a way how to search in Eclipse E4XMI editor, preferably by elementId?

Example: Searching for *com.example.e4.rcp.todo.popupmenu.table*, from Lars Vogel's sample Todo application. I am looking for any tool that would take me quickly from here:

[image]

to here:

[image]

Even for a small sample application it is laborious process, especially for anyone in process of mastering PDE.

The *form* tab does not provide any visible search field. The *list* tabs provides two *filter* controls but none of them seems to find my sample element ID.

The *XMI* tab, the raw XML, has a search bar, but it's buggy. After some struggle I was able to locate the element there, hooray, but there is no link back to form, for more comfortable editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the 'List' tab of the e4xmi editor you can click on the 'elementId' column header to get the elements sorted by id which should make it easy to find the element you want.

Clicking on the first column (labelled 'Go') will take you to the element in the 'Form' tab.

Comment: OK, if this is the only way, that there is in fact no proper search functionality, then a bug/enhancement request should be filled. Here it is: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516167

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, there is a search box in Form tab. It is just not turn on by default. To make it appear go to Window -> Preferences -> Model Editor -> check "Searchable tree on form tab"

Credits to Lars Vogel for notifying me, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516167#c2

Unfortunately it has bugs and limitations. It makes XMI tab read only, I can live with that. One cannot copy to it, only type to it; that is worse. And worst of all, it frequently does not find everything it should :(